# Finding the second solution to this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:**

Consider Bessel's equation

$$x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-p^2)y=0,$$

where $p$ is a constant. Given $y_1=x^{-1/2}\sin(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation in the case $p=1/2$. Show that the differential equation satisfied by a second linearly independent solution is given by:

$$y'+\left(\frac{1}{2x} - \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\right)y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} \sin(x)}.$$

Hence solve Bessel's equation in the case $p=1/2$.

$\\$

I've reached the following point:

$$y_2'-\left(-\frac{1}{2x} +\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\right)y_2=k\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} \sin(x)}$$

with integrating factor $\mu(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sin(x)}$ then,

$$y_2= \frac{k\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \int{\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}}dx.$$

I can't remember how to calculate an integral of this type and proceed. Should I use $u$-substitution or an identity?

Comment: Remember that $(\cot(x))^{\prime} = -\csc^{2}(x)$, that is to say:

$$\int\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(x)}\mathrm{d}x = \int\csc^{2}(x)\mathrm{d}x = -\cot(x) + c$$

Comment: Completely forgot about that. That's helped me reached the second solution :)